# Assign delegate to a class for another class from inside third class

Tags: ios, swift

I have worked with delegate pattern for passing data in the past but that was *one-to-one* sort of interaction like say I need to pass data back from *ViewController B* to *ViewController A* and I set the delegate property defined in B from inside A. Usually we need this kind of delegation.

But I have certain condition where I need to set the delegate property from inside the third, not a ViewController, but a class

Here's how it is laid out -

```
protocol DataPassingDelegate {
  func reloadData()
}

class ButtonView: UIButton {

  // Some function that decide which ViewController is to be displayed
  func destinationVCDecider() {

   // parentController fetched the ViewController in which the button is laid out
   let destinationVCObject = self.parentController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER.JOB_DETAILS_VIEW_CONTROLLER) as! JobDetailsViewController              

   // Setup for passing data via delegate
   let jobsVCObject = JobsViewController()

   destinationVCObject.delegate = jobsVCObject

   // Displaying the Details of the job
   parentController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVCObject, animated: true)  

  }

} 

class JobsViewController: UIViewController,DataPassingDelegate {

  func reloadData() {
   // Reload the jobs from the server
  }

}

class JobDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

  weak var delegate: DataPassingDelegate?

  func navigateBack() {

    delegate?.reloadData()

  }

}
```

`navigateBack()` inside `JobDetailsViewController` will be called when certain event has been triggered

Now, when the `navigateBack()` is called, the `delegate` property turns out to be `nil`

Earlier I used to assign `self` in cases where there was *one-to-one* interaction but here there are a few classes between them that I don't want to pass them all around

Answer (score 0):

Your approach here is correct. You need to debug it. Create your JobsViewController's instance like this-

let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Name", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewID") as JobsViewController.

You can debug whether delegate instance is being passed or not by putting a breakpoint in ViewDidLoad method of JobDetailsViewController.

Another approach you can follow is to use NotificationCenter